# Using the container inside a simple bundle class dont work in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.3

My Error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica::__construct() must implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
>   called in
>   C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\BackendBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   on line 20 and defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica.php line 10

My class grafica:

```
<?php
namespace Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
/**
 * @Route(service="srv_grafica")
 */
class grafica
{
    private $container, $conn, $bdnmgi;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->conn = $this->getConn();
        $this->bdnmgi = $this->getBd();
    }

    public function getConn(){
        return $this->container->get('database_connection');
    }
    public function getBd(){
        return $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getAdministracion()->getNombreEsquemamgi();
    }
```

\ManagerBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

```
services:
    srv_grafica:
        class: Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
```

My DefaultController:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboardAction(Request $peticion)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer_1');
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $esquema = $user->getAdministracion()->getNombreEsquemamgi();
        var_dump($esquema);
        $grafica = new grafica();
```

Comment: Show us where you instantiate the class

Comment: Can you add the declaration of the service please (xml, yml, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the container to your service, below an example how to do it in your services.yml

```
services:

    srv_grafica:
        class: Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
```

Comment: I edited my file services.yml. but dont work, i go to edit my post

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong:

```
$grafica = new grafica();
```

Should be:

```
$grafica = $this->get('srv_grafica');
```